# What is "cyclic shift unitary" on $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, permutation-matrices, circulant-matrices

From page 264 of Brown & Ozawa's [$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-88):

> Let $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be the $n\times n$ complex matrices, and what is the "*cyclic shift unitary of order $n$*" on $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$?

Maybe it is a very basic concept in functional analysis or matrix theory?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247068/339790)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyclic shift operator is the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
       0&1     \\
      &0&1 \\
        & & \ddots \\
&&&&1\\
1&&&&0
     \end{bmatrix}$$
It has order $n$, that is to say, $A^n=I$, and it is a unitary matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sal.